# My classes are empty/null in the viewModel, when creating an object. MVC, EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I got my createPlayer view. It works and loads the images I got stored. And I want to choose one image in the dropdown and store that ID on my playerImageId. But both my classes (images / player) are empty in the `[HttpPost]` controller, when hitting the create button.

The model that is send to the view is this:

```
public ActionResult CreatePlayer()
{
    var images = db.Image.ToList();
    var playerViewModel = new PlayerViewModel(new Player(), images);
    return View(playerViewModel);
}
```

The view looks like this:

```
@model MariedalsIK.Models.PlayerViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Player</legend>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Image, Model.Image.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                                                              {
                                                                                  Text = x.ImageName,
                                                                                  Value = x.Id.ToString()
                                                                              }))
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Player.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Player.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Player.Name)
        </div>
```

The PlayerViewModel looks like this:

```
  public class PlayerViewModel
    {
        public PlayerViewModel(Player player, IEnumerable<Image> images)
        {
            Player = player;
            Image = images;
        }

        public Player Player { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<Image> Image { get; private set; }

        public PlayerViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
```

And the CreatePlayer action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePlayer(PlayerViewModel playerViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Player.Add(playerViewModel.Player);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Teams");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Teams");
}
```

The thing is that it works if I only sends a player to `[HttpPost]` CreatePlayer, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePlayer(Player player)
```

But in that case I don't get the `imageId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view model properties only have private setters. The default model binder cannot set their values. So change your view model like this:

```
public class PlayerViewModel
{
    public Player Player { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Image> Image { get; set; }
}
```

Also your dropdownlist is incorrect. You are attempting to bind it to a complex collection property. You need a simple scalar property to bind the selected value to:

```
public class PlayerViewModel
{
    public Player Player { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public string ImageId { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ImageId)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.ImageId, 
        new SelectList(Model.Images, "Id", "ImageName")
    )
</div>
```